# What means *= in QtCreator .pro files?

Tags: makefile, qt-creator, qmake

Check [this pro file](https://github.com/ialhashim/GeoTopo/blob/master/standalone/standalone.pro). It has lines like that:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /openmp
```

I easily understand a `+=` to add an option or `-=` to remove one...but what does `*=` means here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`Operators`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qmake-language.html#adding-unique-values) section in Qt documentation:

> The `*=` operator adds a value to the list of values in a variable, but
>   only if it is not already present. This prevents values from being
>   included many times in a variable. For example:
>
> ```
> DEFINES *= USE_MY_STUFF
> ```
>
> In the above line, `USE_MY_STUFF` will only be
>   added to the list of pre-processor defines if it is not already
>   defined. Note that the [`unique()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qmake-function-reference.html#unique) function can also be used to ensure
>   that a variable only contains one instance of each value.

Comment: Thanks. However, could you please update your "Operators" link. The page pointed does not contain the pasted text about `*=`.